# Alternating series remainder overestimation

Tags: calculus, summation

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ is approximated using the partial sum $$\sum_{n=0}^3\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

The error bound is $$\frac{(-1)^5}{9!}\approx -0.000003$$

Why is this an overestimation and not an underestimation since it is negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true value is between the partial sum and the partial sum plus the error bound.  So, if the error is negative, the partial sum is an overestimate.

Comment: So do you subtract the error bound from the partial sum?

Comment: Exactly.  If the partial sum is $s$, we know the sum of the series is between $s$ and $s-.000003,$ so $s$ overestimates the sum.