# In an alternating series remainder where the 1st term in remainder is a negative, why is the approximate series an overestimate?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation, divergent-series

Saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863946/alternating-series-remainder-overestimation) but it doesn't go deep enough to help understanding this.
I need help identifying my knowledge gap as I struggle to understand why it is an overestimate. My thinking below results in the approximation being an underestimate, rather than overestimate (which is stated in the answer).

When taking the values of the series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ is approximated using the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Setting up:

1. $\sum^{99}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = S_{99}$ , is the partial sum
2. $\sum^{\infty}_{n=99}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = R_{99}$ , where $S_{99}
       +R_{99} = S$ (Sum of series)
3. First ***term*** of $R_{99} = \frac{(-1)^{101}}{100} = \frac{-1}{100}
       = Rt_{100}$
4. $S_{100}+Rt_{100}$ is the approximation
5. Thus: $S_{99}+Rt_{100} < S < S_{99}$

Since $Rt_{100}$ is the smallest number of the $R_{99}$:
$S_{99}+Rt_{100}(aka \frac{-1}{100})$ < S

This is verified using wolfram alpha:

$S_{99}+Rt_{100} = \sum^{99}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} + (\frac{-1}{100})\approx  0.688172$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%2B1%5D%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C99%7D%5D%5C%2841%29-Divide%5B1%2C100%5D))

$S = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} =\log{2}\approx 0.69315$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%2B1%5D%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%5Cinfty%7D%5D%5C%2841%29))

$S_{99} = \sum^{99}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \approx 0.698172$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%2B1%5D%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C99%7D%5D%5C%2841%29))

Every thing seem to point to the approximation being an underestimate. Why does Khan academy say it is an over estimate? (Ref below)

[image]

---

The part of the question about over or under estimate (which I got the wrong answer on):

[image]

My intuition:

- I suspect it's got something to do with error bound/error estimates, but even then the math should make sense that the approximation should be smaller than the full alternating series thus an ***under*** estimate?(even for a negative 1st term of remainder, $Rt_{100} = \frac{-1}{100}$)
- I'm at [this part of my journey](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-10/v/alternating-series-error-estimation) (quiz) and Khan hasn't really explained error bounds yet, ideally I want to unknot the conflicting math vs my results. Even from reading, error bound seem to just mean the difference between "S and the approximation".

Comment: what is the first thing that one needs to understand with an alternating series that the magnitude of each term is strictly less than the previous one? just calculating the first 3 terms should be enough to perfectly understand what is happening. Calculate $S_1,S_2$ and $S_3$ and you should have got the full picture of what is happening.

Comment: Hint, if calculating up to nth term is overestimate then calculating the (n+1)th term is an under estimate.

Comment: You are right, very helpful @jimjim. I've corrected the set up:  $S_{99}+Rt_{100} < S < S_{99}$ and also added the link to the result $S_{99} = \sum^{99}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \approx 0.698172$. It doesn't seem to change the fact that $S_{99}+Rt_{100} < S$

Comment: Is this correct $S_1>S_3>S_5>\cdots>S_{99}>\cdots>S>\cdots>S_{100}>\cdots>S_6>S_4>S_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure. I suspect the values oscillate between the actual value S=ln(2)? I tried plotting it out on desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hwedcp2pvq

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Haha. The questions remains a mystery...! (or source of confusion!)

Comment: The question is worded in the most stupid way, what is one to understand is that with monotonically decreasing alternating series $| S-S_k|<|a_{k+1}| $ , throwing the term "negative error bound" in the mix is a terrible way to confuse people.

Comment: refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums and completely ignore questions that are asked in an idiotic way, one learns nothing from answering that question.

Comment: Sorry is my question bad or the Khan academy question bad @jimjim ?

Comment: You are right, Khan academy is asking a very confusing useless question

Answer (score 1):

If we visualize $s$, $S_k$, and $R_k$ as points on the real line, where the negative numbers are off to the left and the positive ones off to the right, you can think of the error $R_k$ as the distance you need to walk to get from the partial sum $S_k$ to the actual sum $s$. This intuition works because of the definition of $R_k$.

$$R_k=s-S_k$$

This says the same thing as $s=S_k+R_k$, implying that if the partial sum $S_k$ is greater than $s$, you'll need to walk in the negative direction, aka to the left, to get to $s$. In symbols, this means that $R_k<0$ (similar reasoning holds when $R_k>0$). We can also easily reach this conclusion analytically:

$$S_k>s\iff s-S_k<0\iff R_k<0$$

Let's now consider your situation. You and Khan Academy correctly found the error to be approximately $-0.01$, and hence negative. Applying our intuition here, this means that we need to walk approximately $0.01$ units in the *negative* direction (to the left) to get from $S_{99}$ to the sum $s$. But if we need to walk to the left to get to $s$, then clearly we must've started our walk to the right of $s$! Thus, the partial sum $S_{99}$ must've been greater than the actual sum.

Likewise, if we know that the error is positive, then you need to walk to the right to get to the actual sum $s$, so our partial sum must've been to the left of $s$, i.e. $S_k<s$.

Comment: Thank you @AlannRosas. I follow up to the point where $S_k>s\iff s-S_k<0\iff R_k<0$. I see that the Partial sum is indeed larger than the actual. However, it doesn't seem to answer why the **approximation** $(S_{99}+Rt_{100} = \sum^{99}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} + (\frac{-1}{100})\approx  0.688172)$ is an overestimate when we can see clearly from the wolfphamalpha results says otherwise? $(S = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} =\log{2}\approx 0.69315)$

Comment: @nvs0000 : Where do the Khan citations talk about $S_{100}=S_{99}+Rt_{100}$? All the claims appear to refer to the unchanged $S_{99}$. // One could call $S_{99}+Rt_{100}$ an over-correction, as it overshoots the correct value.

Comment: @nvs0000 when Khan Academy refers to “the approximation”, they’re talking about the partial sum $S_{99}$ by itself, not $S_{99} + \frac{(-1)^{100+1}}{100}$. The number $\frac{(-1)^{100+1}}{100}=-0.01$ is simply an estimate for the error $R_k$, explaining why they said “the approximation”, namely $S_{99}$, is an overestimate.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it's from this video, he said: ”big takeaway: The magnitude of your error is going to be no more than the first term that you’re not including in your partial sum” https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-10/v/alternating-series-error-estimation (20 seconds before it ends)

Comment: @AlannRosas I'm not sure if they'd confuse the partial sum with the approximation. Sal Khan was talking all about how we can use the "partial sum" + "1st term that's not included in the partial sum" to get an approximation. Then bound S: $S_k < S < S_k + $"1st term that's not included in the partial sum". See it here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-10/v/alternating-series-error-estimation

Comment: @nvs0000 : Yes, in absolute terms the next term of the series is an upper bound for the error of the partial sum. In an alternating Leibniz series with the first term positive, the odd-index partial sums are a falling sequence of upper bounds, the even-index partial sums a rising sequence of lower bounds. What you are concerned with is a specialized case of this general claim.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann so is my not using absolute terms causing the discrepancy..?